# List items from database

Tags: react-native

I am using SQLite and I can get the items of the database, but I cant write the items on the Text component:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
{
db.transaction((tx) => {
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM flor where nomePopular like \'%brom%\''
  tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {

    var len = results.rows.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let row = results.rows.item(i);
      alert(row.id) //THE ALERT WORK
      {<Text>row.id</Text>} //TEXT NOT WORKS
    }
  });
});
}
</View>
```

The alert works correctly, but the Text not works :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about SQL but i think `db.transaction` returns a [transaction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction) object, which can't be used to render JSX.

Therefore what you need to do is move it to a separate module as

```
state = {
  rows: [] // Initially an empty array
}

getTransactionResults = () => {
db.transaction((tx) => {
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM flor where nomePopular like \'%brom%\''
  tx.executeSql(sql, [], (tx, results) => {

    var len = results.rows.length;
    this.setState({rows: results.rows.raw()})
  });
});
}

render () {
  const transaction = this.getTransactionResults() //<== Call here to initiate transaction
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
      {
       this.state.rows.map((row) => <Text key={row.id}>{row.id}<Text>)
      }
    </View>
   )
}
```

Comment: not work, I get a error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.rows.map')

Comment: Did you add the initialState as i have mentioned here, also results.rows returns an array right?

Comment: Updated the result

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure `results.rows` are a array. I know that `results.rows.item(i)` is a object

Comment: You may try logging `this.state.rows` directly under `render func` and check the result, what it shows.

Comment: `found: object with keys {item, raw, length}`

Comment: I edit your code, the correct is: `this.setState({rows: results.rows.raw()})` thanks for your help